# User information isn't storing to proper user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, associations

In my Users controller, I have the following method

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if current_user.id == params[:id] # im not sure if this is right
    @answer = Answer.new
  else
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

where

```
class User 
  has_many :answers
end
```

and

```
class Answer 
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I open another user (A) by the signed in user (B), I want A's quiz questions (which also belongs_to User through a has_one association) to have the answers by B.

As is, if B answers A's questions, and then I log in with A, they will have the same answers of the original B to A.

If it helps, in my Answers controller I have the following methods.

```
def create
  @answer = current_user.answers.build(answer_params)
  if @answer.save
    flash[:success] = "Updated"
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    if @answer.update(answer_params)
      format.html { redirect_to '/', notice: 'Answers were successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @answer }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def answer_params
  params.require(:answer).permit(:r1, :r2, :r3, :r4, :r5)
end
```

and I also have the migration

```
class AddUserIdToAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :answers, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

EDIT:
Quizzes Controller (belongs_to User, User has_one :quiz)

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController

def edit
@quiz = Quiz.find(params:[id])
end

def create
@quiz = current_user.build_quiz(quiz_params)
if @quiz.save
  flash[:success] = "Updated"
  redirect_to '/'
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
@quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
  if @quiz.update(quiz_params)
    format.html { redirect_to '/', notice: 'Quiz was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @quiz }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @quiz.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end


  def quiz_params
 params.require(:quiz).permit(:q1, :q2, :q3, :q4, :q5)
  end

  def show
 @quizzes = Quiz.all
  end

 end
```

and my Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
 devise_for :users

 root to: 'welcome#landing'
 resources :users, :quizzes, :answers
```

end

Answer (score 0):

I am not gone through every aspect. But one issue in your show action.

```
if current_user.id == params[:id] # im not sure if this is right
```

With this you will not get new form. Because `params[:id]` type is string and `current_user.id` type is integer. So it will always return false.

Try change like :

```
if current_user.id == params[:id].to_i
```

Or compare user object directly

```
if current_user == @user
```

Comment: This produces the same results as in the OP (if B answers A's questions, and then I log in with A, they will have the same answers of the original B to A.)

Comment: Paste your routes and questions controller. What is the relation between questions and user. You must pass question_to get answer for a particular question

Comment: each user has_one quiz, and a quiz belongs_to user. Check above edit for routes/question controller

Answer (score 0):

Try my suggestion helpisgood

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])

 if current_user == @user
    @answer = Answer.new
 else
    @answer = Answer.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
 end
end
```